# Asp.net MVC Client validation, strange behavior

Tags: asp.net-mvc, client-side-validation

When i write :

```
   <% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm())
    { %>
       <%: Html.ValidationSummary(false) %>
       <%: Html.EditorForModel() %>
       <p><input type="submit" name="name" value="Register" />   </p>
    <% } %>
```

My client validation works perfectly.

but when i change " <%: Html.EditorForModel() %>" with (all the code around is the same) :

```
   <div>User name<%: Html.EditorFor(x=>x.Name) %></div>
   <div>Password<%: Html.EditorFor(x=>x.Password)%></div>
   <div>Verify password <%: Html.EditorFor(x=>x.Password2) %></div>
```

Client side validation doesn't work.

am i missing something ? what "EditorForModel" does, that i didn't ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're missing validation messages.  EditorForModel() is setting this up for you.

```
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.Name)
```

Comment: Thanks i thought it's a part of the "EditorFor"